# Complete URL from response in urllib3

Tags: urllib3

I wonder how I can retrieve the complete URL (including the encoded fields) from a `urllib3` response.

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
resp = http.request(
    "GET",
    "https://httpbin.org/get",
    fields={"hello": "world"} 
)
```

`resp.geturl()` only returns the base URL (`https://httpbin.org/get`), but not the full URL (`https://httpbin.org/get?hello=world`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the urlencode method from the urllib.parse module to encode the fields and add them to the URL. Here's an example:

```
import urllib3
import urllib.parse

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

fields = {"hello": "world"}
encoded_fields = urllib.parse.urlencode(fields)

url = "https://httpbin.org/get?" + encoded_fields
resp = http.request("GET", url)

print(resp.geturl())
```

This will return the full URL with the encoded fields: https://httpbin.org/get?hello=world